# SQL query won't work when used from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I got a question about these two queries.

The first one does work, the second one does not. I know I'm missing something, I can't see it though!

```
SELECT Kod10 
FROM Adminview 
WHERE Kvartal = 1 
 AND Användarnamn = 'LOLGATAN13' 
 AND År = '2013'
```

And this is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Checkinpvalue]
   @Inmånad varchar(50),
   @Användarnamn varchar(50),
   @Kvartal int
AS
    SELECT Kod10 
    FROM Adminview 
    WHERE Kvartal = @Kvartal 
      AND Användarnamn = @Användarnamn 
      AND År = @Inmånad
```

Used like this:

```
EXEC Checkinpvalue 1, 'LOLGATAN13', '2013'
```

Edit: The reason I'm asking this is because I don't like using selects directly. I would prefer using them through a procedure.

Edit: Answered! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your parameters is wrong?!

```
EXEC Checkinpvalue '2013', 'LOLGATAN13', 1
```

Comment: Oh, haha. This happens when you dont got enough sleep. Thank you.